# How to create a function that loops back to the first player from the last player?

Tags: python, while-loop

This is what I got so far. This game can have multiple players up to len(players).

I'd like it to keep prompting the different players each time to make their move.
So, for example, if there are 3 players A B C, if it was player's A turn, I want the next player to be player B, then the next player to be C, and then loop back to player A.

Using only while loops, if statements, and booleans if possible.

PLAYERS = 'ABCD'

```
def next_gamer(gamer):
    count = 0
    while count < len(GAMERS):
    if gamer == GAMERS[0]:
          return GAMERS[count + 1]
    if gamer == GAMERS[-1]
          return GAMER[0]
    count = count + 1
```

Comment: Can you be more precise on what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: You seem to have a small formatting error in your code, probably just from pasting it. You may want to edit it and indent your if's and "count = count + 1" so they fall into your while loop, just for clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't use the .index() method, I think what you are trying to do is this:

```
    def next_gamer(gamer):
        count = 0
        while count < len(GAMERS):
            if gamer == GAMERS[count]:
                return GAMERS[count + 1]
            count = count + 1
        return GAMERS[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution to your previous question, involving generators :

```
turn=0
def gameIsFinished():
    global turn
    turn = turn+1
    return turn >10

def cycle(iterable):
    while True:
        for item in iterable:
            if gameIsFinished():
                return
            yield item

for player in cycle([1,2,3]):
    print player
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! However, for my game I'm not allowed to use anything but while loops, if-statements, and booleans. Could you replicate the results using a while loop?

Answer (score 0):

You can just have your function return the next gamer in your list GAMERS using a simple statement like this one which works regardless of which gamer you are currently at in the game:

> return GAMERS[GAMERS.index(gamer)+1]

unless the present gamer is the last in the list which you can test using the following if statement:

> if GAMERS.index(gamer) == len(GAMERS) - 1:
>
> > return GAMERS[0]

in which case you return the first gamer.

Comment: Note: I think you would want your while loop to be outside of your function "next_gamer()". Once your function returns something, it exits the function and thus exits the while loop.

Comment: Thanks for your help. However, I'm restricted to using only while loops, booleans, and if-statements for my game. How would you go about it without methods?

Comment: Well that's no fun! Then you don't need a while loop, just as many if statements as there are players. Or you store the players as a dictionary? You should redefine your question then.

Comment: The number of players can change, hence the need for a while loop to count < len(players). With the length of the string assigned to players as the number of players that will be present. And we haven't learned about dictionaries yet, so I don't think we'll be able to use that also..

Comment: Oh ok got it. I posted another answer without the index method.